# Past participle used as an adjective

Tags: grammar, british-english, past-participles

I found this "blog" where  the point I refer to is fully explained.  http://englishharmony.com/past-participle-as-adjective/

Since the moment I read it, I've been wondering if

> It was already burned when I came here.

shares the same meaning as

> When I came here, it had already been burned.

I don't know whether my examples are correct. If you have a look at the website above-mentioned, you will see the examples given, which are

> 'He  is gone'
>   . Vs.
>   "He  has gone'.

If they mean the same, theoretically, in addition to the examples I gave  you at the beginning of my question,  I might say

> " He  was gone' /
>   "he  had gone"

couldn't I?   The choice depends on the context, according to that blog.

Comment: Good point! You can decide which form to apply between the 2 possible options in each case.

Comment: So, is it the same for passive?    I mean "It is said"  , does it share the same meaning of "it had been said".  According to what I know, there's should be difference as presente perfect implies a long-term action, i mean, it is said for a while, while the other  isn't. Am i right?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly a pasta participle is, but it sounds delicious.

Comment: @EnglishStudent Not at all: participles deployed as adjectives are acceptable in any register.

Comment: Ahahahahahahahahaahahaahha sorry. My telephone is set on italian language so it changes words when i type. In English.    Rotfl

Comment: *nere*? "near" or "here"?

Comment: Moreover, 'he was gone' and 'he had gone' are not the same tense. HE WAS GONE is simple past tense similar to 'I was sick' or 'they were rich' where was/ were is the verb form 'to be' used in simple past tense with the adjective 'sick' , 'rich', 'gone', etc. WHEREAS 'he had gone' is past perfect tense.

Comment: @Stoney B I only specifically meant that participle deployed as adjective, when substituted as in OP's example, will change the tense. IT IS QUITE OK if the tense can be altered.

Comment: The blog you referred to discusses the special form 'past participle used as adjective' for spoken English -- what he means is that when people actually speak English, they don't speak like we write it. **The tense can be changed.** So we get forms like 'the work is done' for 'the work has been done' -- it is a simplification using the participle as adjective. However, you can't use the same substitution in writing **without changing the tense** and therefore it's more suitable for creative work (fiction) and informal emails. If you don't mind changing the tense, your substitution is quite OK.

Comment: May "it was burned " be also translated in a passive say or burned here, after the verb be, is merely adjective?

Comment: Dunno whether my instance is right. What I meant was, is there a case where in the same kind of senfence a past  participle might be an adjective as well as being a  passive?

Comment: Here are my example: i was surprised.    If i am correct, it could be an adjective and a passive form(surprised by...) so, i  suppose when we come across sentences like this, the true meaning depends on the context

Comment: This is the past-participle USED as adjective, wit a small twist: . 'It burns (present) -- it burned (past) -- it had burned (past participle)" the adjective form is spelled as **'burnt'** -- *It was (found) burnt.* HOWEVER, if you say 'it was burned' the tense becomes past perfect (passive voice) and means "it was burned (by somebody)" which is a slightly different meaning. So the past participle can only be adjective **or** passive voice in this particular case, not both at the same time.

Comment: In your other example, "I am surprised" **can be** read as both adjective and passive voice.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the fact that burnt is the actual adjective.  U said that my sentence become  past perfect if translated into passive form (which I did corrrectly at the beginning of my question where i re-written it this way "it had already...". ) but i don t know if you  mistake sth but u said it was past perfect but u actually wrote the simple past passive

Comment: I worked it out because I focused on the time line  :i came there and the car  was already burned, so It.means it happened earlier and past perfect is the only tense  which translates  an older action